# Does git track the remote URL if it's changed in .ssh/config?

Tags: git, ssh

Assume I have this in `/home/ibug/.ssh/config`

```
Host GitHub github GH gh
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

And the in a local repo, I run

```
git remote set-url origin gh:iBug/foo
```

Does git remember `gh:iBug/foo` or `git@github.com:iBug/foo`?

Comment: Git doesn't know and doesn't care about `.ssh/config`. Use `git remote -v` to find the answer to your question.

Comment: @axiac You mean I can `git remote set-url blahblah:blah/blah`?

Comment: You can `git remote set-url blahblah:blah/blah` as well. This command only writes the URL in the repo's configuration. Nothing more. `git fetch` is the one that uses `ssh` to talk to the remote server. It passes the URL to `ssh` and `ssh` is the one that consults its `.ssh/config` and expands `gh` to `github.com`. Take a look into `.git/config`; you'll find the `blah-blah` URL there unchanged, under the `[remote "origin"]` section.

Comment: @axiac Sounds like an answer. Would you mind posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never checked, but judging from other parts of configuration, I'd say git simply remembers the "remote url" text as-is provided by you, so `blahblah:blah/blah` would probably be stored exactly like that.

Since GIT supports multiple remotes, you risk nothing by trying it out yourself. Just use `git remote -v` or read `.git/config` and see what's there.

Let me see on some git repo I use currently

```
quetzalcoatl@LAP049 MINGW32 /c/w/-path-redacted- (develop)
$ git remote add asdf "KJH&*^^IGJH*"

quetzalcoatl@LAP049 MINGW32 /c/w/-path-redacted- (develop)
$ git remote -v
asdf    KJH&*^^IGJH* (fetch)
asdf    KJH&*^^IGJH* (push)
--other urls redacted--

quetzalcoatl@LAP049 MINGW32 /c/w/-path-redacted- (develop)
$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
---other sections redacted---
[remote "asdf"]
    url = KJH&*^^IGJH*
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/asdf/*
```

So, well, it seems to store verbatim copy of what was given in command line params.

Comment: So `git remote set-url` has the same effect of editing `.git/config` by hand?

Comment: @iBug it has the same effect but it's recommended to not edit `.git/config` by hand. Afaik, everything that is stored in that file can be edited through Git commands. Read about [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).